# How can I play H.264 RTSP video in Windows 8 Metro C# XAML app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, h.264, rtsp

I have a device that provides an H.264 video stream from a URL like:
    rtsp://192.168.0.10:554/videoservice

Since this is live video I don't need to be able to control it (pause, rewind, etc), just play. Is this supported by [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) or another standard class, do I need something like [Smooth Streaming Client SDK](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/04423d13-3b3e-4741-a01c-1ae29e84fea6) or is this a lot more complicated than I thought?

Update:
I downloaded Microsoft's [Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/) but this doesn't play the stream either. I can't find anything in the examples about RTSP.

Update:
I used [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to compare the packets that [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) (which works) sends with MediaElement and Player Framework and neither of them seemed to use RTSP protocol. Instead they're sending [WPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) packets to a different address, even though I've provided the IP address of the source. Why is this necessary? Is there any way of turning this behaviour off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/1709d85b-97b4-425c-a5f5-3edc4d7539e6).  You need to wrap your data in MPEG-4 Part 14 containers and then pass them into [`MediaElement.SetSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244338).  It appears you can't do this just using the documented API.  Here is the important information from the link:

> We don't support RTP but rather the MPEG-4 Part 14 container format.
>   You will need to write our own source to be able to parse the data a
>   pass it directly to the Microsoft decoder. At this time we do not have
>   any samples on how to write a custom source and have it loaded from
>   your Metro style app. Unfortunately it is not possible to simply use
>   the documentation to figure out how to do this. I have been talking
>   with Stan and we are trying to figure out how and when we can make
>   this information available.  As soon as this information is available
>   I will announce it on my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/mediasdkstuff/.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx) is a list of supported video formats.

There is also an example [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096/view/SourceCode) of how to extend the media class which might have an example of how to do something similar to what you are asking.

There is a similar example [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MediaStreamSource-media-dfd55dff).

Comment: Is there anything specific you would want added to my answer?

Comment: No, just frustrated that Microsoft make it so difficult to support RTSP. This is way more work than I have time for right now so I'll have to shelve the project.