# How to use LibVLC.NET libary in windows store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, h.264, rtsp, libvlc

I am trying to Stream an IP camera into Windows store app. Ip camera supports RTSP and H.264 video format. So, I thought I should use **LibVLC.NET** library for this purpose. But I can't find any example or sample code for this purpose. Please tell me that I am going into right way and can use LibVLC.NET for this purpose.

Also tell me if there is another library or solution for streaming an IP camera with H.264 RTSP video.

I have also checked this post:
[How can I play H.264 RTSP video in Windows 8 Metro C# XAML app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994188/how-can-i-play-h-264-rtsp-video-in-windows-8-metro-c-sharp-xaml-app)

But if your answer is same as here recommended then please give me some help that how can I wrap data in MPEG-4 Part 14 containers and then pass them into MediaElement.SetSource.

Any help would be really appreciated and Thanks in Advance!